# Joomla Server Error 500 after own template installation

Tags: joomla, server-error, joomla3.0

I made a template which works perfectly fine locally, but when I install it on a server and set it to default, I get a server error 500. All other (default) templates seem to be working fine, though... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View this tutorial (Admin Tools - Change Folder and File Permissions):

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/admin-tools-the-quick-and-easy-way-to-change-folder-and-file-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your server error log to see if there is anything more detailed.

500 is a generic error (if no other information is provied by Joomla!).